# How can I use PHP to return a software version number?

Tags: php, git, shell, version

I am working on a project and part of the process is to check which version of software installed on the host server, specifically Git for this case. From the command line I can run `git --version` which would return something similar to:

`git version 1.8.5.2 (Apple Git-48)`

I can use the following code to return the value from the command.

```
<?php

$gitVersion = exec('git --version');

return $gitVersion;

?>
```

However, is there a more efficient way to have the output look like the following:

`1.8.5.5`

Comment: Not really, executing a shell command maybe for the best in this case.

Comment: Thank you, so is there a recommended way to strip everything except the numbers? Maybe using regex?

Comment: Since `git version ` has a fixed length, using substrings is probably easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    return shell_exec("git --version | awk '{print $3}'");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use explode() and return the second index.

Example:

```
$parts = explode(' ', shell_exec('git --version'));
return $parts[2];
```